# get list of checkbox id and value from a div and pass it to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I got a checkbox list populated by my viewmodel. I specify id and value in the checkbox element. I need to save these information in the database. Currently i have it where i take the checkbox id and checkbox value, puts them in a key value pair and i intend to make an ajax call to my controller. Is there a better approach into doing this (mvc)? How would you do it?
Thanks

My code:

VIEW

```
   <div class = "divSubject">
     @foreach (var item in Model.dictionarySubject)
            {
     <div>
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.Value, new { @id = item.Key.subjectID})
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Key.subjectName)
    </div>

            }
   </div>
```

JQuery

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function () {
 var dict = []; // create an empty array
              $('.divSubject input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                  var id = $(this).attr('id')
                  dict.push({
                      key: id,
                      value: $(this).attr('checked')
                  });
                  alert(JSON.stringify(dict))
              });
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the NAME property of the checkbox, which is part of a standard for POST DATA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of a DOM element has some limitations. For example it cannot start with a number. I would recommend you using the HTML5 data-* attributes to hold this metadata information:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(
    model => item.Value, 
    new { data_id = item.Key.subjectID }
)
```

and then inside your javascript:

```
$('.divSubject input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id')
    dict.push({
        key: id,
        value: $(this).attr('checked')
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(dict))
});
```

Other than that your code seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine, but I believe that you want to take pairs of key and Boolean value. In this case, consider below code:

```
dict.push({
     key: id,
     value: !!$(this).attr('checked')
});
```

$(this).attr('checked') will return "checked" or null, not a Boolean value.